# PowerPoint embedded video does not play visibly. Sometimes audio can be heard

Tags: video, embedding, ole, microsoft-powerpoint

On a company-issued PC (Dell Latitude D630 running Windows XP SP3), using PowerPoint 2003 (11.8324.8324) SP3.  If I embed a video of any supported type (WMV, AVI, MPEG) using a Media Player OLE object, the video does not visibly play when the presentation is in Slide Show mode.  It also does not play if I right-click and select "Play".  Sometimes, but not every time, you can hear the audio from the file, but the video never plays.

This can be reproduced on every PC in my department, all Dell laptops of various vintages running the same version of Windows and Office.

Embedding itself works.  For instance, I can embed a SWF file as a Shockwave Flash object and it works perfectly.

We can hyperlink to the same videos and they play fine, but it's clumsier and not as elegant or useful.

Any suggestions on how to proceed would be much appreciated.

Comment: Did any of the solutions work?

Comment: Nope.  As mentioned in the comments to the questions, all suggestions were either irrelevant, or things I had already tried.

Answer (score 1):

**This issue may occur if any one of the following conditions is true:**

- The hardware acceleration setting of
  the display device is too high.
- The required codec is missing or
  damaged.
- Conflicting third-party video
  software is installed on the
  computer.
- The video acceleration of Windows
  Media Player is too high.

The solution to all of these issues can be found [here](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/905167).

Comment: Coming back to this old question: it happens with acceleration set to be zero in both WMP and Windows, with any codec, and the only video software on the box is WMP. It's some weirdness in the company setup.

Answer (score 1):

I have had the exact same problem before, an I have found the solution to be to transcode the video into wmv. The problem is that you are probably missing a required codec. Just transcode the video into wmv and you should be OK. What format are you using?

Comment: As mentioned in the question, I have tried AVI, WMV, and MPEG video.  All fail.  I can play FLV video using a Flash (SWF) player (as opposed to embedding Windows Media Player), but that's too complex a setup for most of our staff.

Comment: Does the video use an MPEG 1 or 2 codec? I.e. when you got the video, did it use an MPEG codec to encode the wma?

Comment: I've tried MPEG 1, MPEG 2, MPEG 4 ASP (DiVX), WMV9 and WMA9, and even MJPEG.  Nothing.

Answer (score 0):

I have had this problem as well. I think you should try MPEG-1 (*not* MPEG-2) video if you haven't yet, that worked for me and should probably always work.

Comment: I've tried both MPEG 1 and 2. Nothing.  The embedded video player turns black and ... that's it.

Answer (score 0):

1. I had the same problem. Try this:
2. Insert | Object | Browse for file - your video clip
3. To play when the slide is clicked, do this:
   a. Slide Show | Custom Automation | Add Effect | Object Actions | Activate Contents
4. If you don't want the warning coming up when you play, then do this:
   Tools | Options | Security | Macro Security | Low

This process inserts the video clip into the presentation - you then only need the ppt, you don't need to have the file with the video clip also

Comment: thanks, but I had already tried that. (This question is approaching a year old, I've tried lots of things.) When activated the embedded object opens a separate Windows Media Player window which then ... doesn't play anything.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

1. insert the movie from file
2. on the actual slide in edit mode right click mouse while pointer is on black box
3. select edit movie object from the menu that should have come up
4. Move mouse pointer to box - zoom to full screen and click left mouse button so tick shows

I was having similar problems and this worked for me.

Comment: Not for me. Freezes PowerPoint entirely. Thanks for trying on this very old question, though. My company will be upgrading me to PP 2010 soon, and in any case we're largely abandoning PP in favor of SMART Notebook anyway.

Answer (score 0):

I have Powerpoint 2010 and under the File button is a choice to `Optimize Media Compatibility` and it worked.  Why it would not work on my own computer without first making it “compatible” is a mystery, but this step worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

in PPT 2013, go into 'File' - 'Options' - 'Advanced' and tick 'Disable Slide Show Hardware Graphics Acceleration'

Comment: Already suggested back in 2010, and already shown not to be the problem.

Answer (score 0):

My problem was answered by Andy Grant above "in PPT 2013, go into 'File' - 'Options' - 'Advanced' and tick 'Disable Slide Show Hardware Graphics Acceleration'"

I'm using PP 2016 and embedded vids played in presentation mode but not edit mode.  Tried using another vid player but didn't work.  Did Andy's fix and Voila....fixed.

Answer (score -1):

For anyone having this issue with embedded youtube vids:

1. Open your Internet Explorer browser and go to a website with flash content like YouTube.
2. Click on the "Gear" icon which is at the top right-hand side corner of the browser window or press the Windows key + X.
3. Click on the "Compatibility View Setting" and add those sites that you are having flash content issues.
4. Check the "Display intranet sites, in compatibility view" as well as Use “Microsoft compatibility lists” options.
5. Restart the browser and the problem will be fixed.

Comment: The question is about videos in PowerPoint, not in IE.

Comment: ...but IE settings might very well affect other Microsoft software, probably including PowerPoint, @xenoid? (It surely affects Excel.)